# Why do digits in bash script names screw up path lookups?

Tags: mac-osx, bash

I've got a simple script that lists a bunch of EC2 servers and automates me connecting to them.  This script lives at `~/bin/ec2` My PATH looks something like:

```
/Users/rob/bin:/Users/rob:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Whenever I call `ec2` I get:

-bash: /Users/rob/ec2: No such file or directory

Unless I give it the full path, then it'll work. If I rename the script to just `ec` then I can run it from anywhere like expected. Have digits in script names always been a problem like this? I'm on Mac OSX.

Comment: I doubt it's the digit. Does it work if you rename it "ec3"?

Answer (score 3):

```
-bash: /Users/rob/ec2: No such file or directory
```

and your script lives here: `~/bin/ec2`

Is there a file or directory at /Users/rob/ec2 that's not a script?

Answer (score 0):

I would look for an alias, a function or a broken symlink. To check the first two, try:

```
type -a ec2
```